# Webpack won't treeshake unused named export objects (using Create React App)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, tree-shaking

Small repo which showcases the issue: https://github.com/Huuums/repro-webpack-treeshaking-object-issue

I have a `customIcons.jsx` file which exports a few SVG paths (some of which I may or may not want to use at some point). I export only 2 of the 4 icons into `App.js` (in above example).

`import { abacus, addressBook } from './customIcons';`

However when I now run `yarn build` the bundle size is as big as if I imported all 4 icons. It does not change at all depending on how many icons I import into `App.js`. Only when I omit the whole import statement (not importing anything from the file) I can see that the bundle size of the `main.[hash].chunk.js` decreases.

Am I doing something wrong here that webpack does not treeshake the unused objects?

Answer (score 2):

https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free

Turns out you have to mark your package as "sideEffectfree" for treeshaking to take place.

Setting `"sideEffects": false` inside the package.json the issue.